# Calculating the loan from amortization.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

I was not quite sure what the question was asking and I would like to have some input.

a), Is it asking us to actually calculate knowing what each principal paid? or

b), Working from almost complete scratch from the given information?

> A loan of present value $L$ is made with payments starting 1 quarter after the loan was made.  Each quarter has an effective interest rate of $i=0.2$.  Each payments consists of $\$250$ plus the interest accumulated from each of the outstanding balance.  If the payment is complete right after the 12th payment, what is $L$?

This is rather a special problem where in an example, it is known that $L=3000$ and each interest added for the payment periods are $I_1=60, I_2=55, \cdots , I_{12}=5$ which means that each payments are $K_1=310, K_2=305, \cdots, K_{12}=255$.

So, the value of $L$ can be "confirmed" as

$$\begin{align}
L& =310v+305v^2+\cdots 255v^{12}\\
&= (310v+310v^2+\cdots 310v^{12})-(5v^2+10v^3+\cdots 55v^{11})\\
&=310a_{\overline {12} \rceil .02}-5v((Ia)_{\overline {11} \rceil .02})\\
& \approx 3278.36-278.36
\end{align}$$

But I'm not sure if the question meant to have us do this.

What if I did not know what $L$ was in the first place?
Would that not be a more natural problem?

If so, all I know is that

$$L = (250+Li)v+(250+OB_1i)v^2+ \cdots +(250+OB_{12}iv^{12})$$

where each $OB_j$ is the outstanding balance.

I know that $OB_{t}=OB_{t+1}-PR_{t+1}$ where $PR_j$ is the principal paid and each $OB$ will depend on $L$ and it seems solvable, but I haven't succeeded so far.

May I ask for some help?

Thanks

Comment: Is it an exam that you have to solve this problem.  Could an excel way solving the problem be OK.  I know of a slick way to calculate it in EXCEL. Would you be interested?

Comment: @satishramanathan Wow.  It's amazing that you are able to solve this problem with EXCEL.  Unfortunately, I am still a newbie in this and have no idea how to use computers to even calculate an average.  I know that some day I will needed, so if it's not too much to ask I am interested in what you have to say so that maybe in the future I can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a loan amortization with equal principal payments $P=250$ for $n=12$ periods at an interest rate $i=2\%$. This is known aslso as Italian amortization plan.

Thus $L=nP=3000$ and for the other quantities:
$$
\begin{align*}
D_k&=D_{k-1}-P=\frac{n-k}{n}S & &\text{debt at time }k \\
I_k&=D_{k-1}i=(n-k+1)\frac{S}{n}i & &\text{interest at time }k\\
R_k&=I_k+P_k=(n-k+1)\frac{S}{n}i+\frac{S}{n} &&\text{payment at time }k
\end{align*}
$$

```
n       R           P          I        D
0                                  L=3,000.00 
1    310.00      250.00      60.00   2,750.00 
2    305.00      250.00      55.00   2,500.00 
3    300.00      250.00      50.00   2,250.00 
4    295.00      250.00      45.00   2,000.00 
5    290.00      250.00      40.00   1,750.00 
6    285.00      250.00      35.00   1,500.00 
7    280.00      250.00      30.00   1,250.00 
8    275.00      250.00      25.00   1,000.00 
9    270.00      250.00      20.00     750.00 
10   265.00      250.00      15.00     500.00 
11   260.00      250.00      10.00     250.00 
12   255.00      250.00       5.00       -   
               3,000.00     390.00
```